# creating a telephone directory using the standard template library list or vector and multimap

Tags: c++

I have a simple telephone directory but i want to modify it so that i can search for a list for a lastname and it should return the firstnames that have the same lastname.One person can have more than one number, and one number can belong to more than one person (members of a family).a telephone number in general case can have non-numeric characters, for example if i have a list of names like this below

```
john williams
smart williams
hendrix james
drey williams
```

if i enter williams or search williams it should return

```
john williams
smart willams
drey williams
```

i want use `Map<String,List<String>>.`

```
class name {
  string str;
public:
  name() { 
      str = ""; 
  }
  name(string s) { 
      str = s; 
  }
  string get() { 
      return str; 
  }
};

// Define less than relative to name objects.
bool operator<(name a, name b){
   return a.get() < b.get();
}

class surname {
  string str;
public:
  surname() { 
      str = ""; 
  }
  surname(string s) { 
      str = s; 
  }
  string get() { 
      return str; 
  }
};

int main()
{
  map<name, surname> directory;

  directory.insert(pair<name, surname>(name("James"), surname("williams")));
  directory.insert(pair<name, surname>(name("Coz"), surname("williams")));
  directory.insert(pair<name, surname>(name("James"),  surname("trues")));
  directory.insert(pair<name, surname>(name("Tni"),surname("mutton")));

  // given a name, find number
  string str;
  cout << "Enter name: ";
  cin >> str;

  map<name, surname>::iterator p;

  p = directory.find(name(str));
  if(p != directory.end()) 
    cout << "surname: " <<  p->second.get();
  else
    cout << "Name not in directory.\n";
    system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What's `Map<String,List<String>>`? Are you using _Java_ ?

Comment: @n.m. i want to modify the above code which is in c++,i want to create one class that will have a list or vector that will contain names and surnames,if i search for a surname and that has first names associted with it it should return all the names and surnames associated with that name the code above just returns one name n surname.....hope im a bit clear

Comment: what did you try so far ? A std::multimap is not that difficult to use, give it a try !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is a key/value pair container, which means you have to define what will be your key and what will be your value, in this particular case you want the surname as a key, and a list of names related to that surname as a value. As you already noticed you can achieve that with a map of vectors, where the vectors are your values:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector <std::string> > directory;
```

This is a working example of what you want to achieve (I replaced the name and surname structs for strings since I dont see the point on using them, but you can change it back if you want)

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector <std::string> > directory;

    directory["williams"].push_back("James");
    directory["williams"].push_back("Coz");
    directory["trues"].push_back("James");
    directory["mutton"].push_back("Tni");

    // given a name, find number
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Enter surname: ";
    std::cin >> str;

    std::map<std::string, std::vector <std::string> >::iterator p;

    p = directory.find(str);
    if(p != directory.end())
    {
      std::string key = p->first;
      std::vector<std::string> names = p->second;

      for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i)
         std::cout << key << " " << names[i] << std::endl;

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Name not in directory.\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

For input williams this will output:

> ```
> Enter surname: williams
> williams James
> williams Coz
> ```

To add more names to "williams" you just have to keep pushing back names to that vector:

```
    directory["williams"].push_back("Luis");
    directory["williams"].push_back("Pedro");
    directory["williams"].push_back("Juan");
```

hope it helps.